# почему g++ не может слинковать библиотеку?

Tags: c++, mingw, компоновщик

Windows 10 64-bit 
Qt 5.12.2 mingw73_32

```
g++ -shared -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -Wl,--out-implib,debug\libapp.a -o debug\app.dll @object_script.botsapp.Debug  -lwintrust -lcrypt32 -lopengl32 -lAdvapi32 ... libodb.a ...
```

Вываливает кучу ошибок типа

```
debug/orm/odbstoremanager.o: In function `ZN3orm15ODBStoreManagerC2Eb': lib/orm/odbstoremanager.cpp:507: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3odb14schema_catalog13create_schemaERNS_8databaseERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb'
```

Поиск строки ZN3odb14schema_catalog13create_schemaERNS_8databaseERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb показывает, что такая функция експортируется libodb.a .

В чем может быть причина такой ошибки?

Comment: А разве статические библиотеки линкуются не через -lname (в вашем случае  -lodb вместо libodb.a). Еще такая библиотека может быть собрана другой версией/другим компилятором и тогда имя этой функции может не совпасть. Ну и еще один интересный вариант - когда-то давно сталкивался что g++ (кажется на убунте) не все равно в каком порядке передавать ему ключи, но подробностей уже не помню

Comment: "Старый баг лучше новых двух..." - в Qt mingw 72_32 оказались свои особенности qmake. Добавление -lodb в .pro в Makefile.debug/relese заменяется на <fullPath>\odb.dll.a, которого нет. Вылечил добавлением в pro-файл прямой ссылки QMAKE_LFLAGS += <fullPath>\libodb.dll.a